# How to delete git zombie branches?

Tags: git, branch

I converted a Subversion repository to Git a couple weeks ago.  I'm left with a bunch of branches I no longer need, but can't delete.  What's worse, in the process of trying to get rid of the svn/whatever branches, I now find myself with branches with "origin" duplicated.  Here's a fragment of my branch list:

```
% git branch -a | egrep 'svn/partial|master'
* master
  origin/master
  origin/origin/master
  svn/partial
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/origin/master
  remotes/svn/partial
```

I appear to be able to delete the svn/partial branch, but not the remotes/svn/partial branch:

```
% git branch -D svn/partial
Deleted branch svn/partial (was 373a64c).
% git branch -D remotes/svn/partial
error: branch 'remotes/svn/partial' not found.
```

If I git-fetch, svn/partial is recreated, and I get another layer of "origin/" branches:

```
% git push
Everything up-to-date
% git fetch
From .
...
 * [new branch]      origin/origin/origin/master -> origin/origin/origin/master
...
 * [new branch]      svn/partial -> svn/partial
```

Yikes!  They are multiplying like tribbles:

```
% git br -a | egrep 'svn/partial|master'
* master
  origin/master
  origin/origin/master
  origin/origin/origin/master
  svn/partial
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/origin/master
  remotes/origin/origin/origin/master
  remotes/svn/partial
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I delete a Git branch both locally and in GitHub?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-in-github)

Answer (score 1):

`git branch -d <branch>` deletes a local branch.  The remote branch isn't in your local repo, so you can't delete  it from your local repo.

To delete it from the remote repo there are a few equivalent commands, the canonical one is:

```
git push origin :svn/partial
```

This says to push nothing (i.e. a non-existent branch) to the remote branch `svn/partial`, which will cause the remote branch to become non-existent ... which is Git's way of saying delete it :)

Recent versions of Git support a more friendly syntax:

```
git push origin --delete svn/partial
```

Comment: And after deleting the remote branches, run `git remote prune origin` to also delete the tracked `remotes/origin/*` branches from your local repository.